# Accessing Javascript Array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var elements = [];
elements = [{user:'random1',name:'Adam' , postal:'WA'},
            {user:'random2',name:'Brad' , postal:'NY'},
            {user:'random3',name:'Clark', postal:'WY'},
            {user:'random4',name:'Dave' , postal:'CA'}];
```

I am trying to access the individual elements within this array

My code so far is:

```
for (var j=0; j<=elements.length; j++){
    console.log("Name :" + elements[j].name + "User :"+elements[j].postal);
}
```

I have tried the other variations of the for loop as well. But not able to access the elements. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *"But not able to access the elements."* Can you elabroate on that? What happens exactly? How you access the array seems fine. The loop should use `<` though, not `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove `=` in your `for` statement it should work fine, without errors

```
for (var j=0; j<elements.length; j++){
 console.log("Name :" + elements[j].name + "User :"+elements[j].postal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript Array index starts from 0;

```
j<=elements.length
```

here when j reach to 4(elements.length) its giving error.
it should be like

```
for (var j=0; j<elements.length; j++){
 console.log("Name :" + elements[j].name + "User :"+elements[j].postal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution

```
for( i in elements){
    console.log("Name :" + elements[j].name + "User :"+elements[j].postal);
}
```

OR

```
elements.forEach(function(user){
  console.log("Name :" + user.name + "User :" + user.postal);
}
```